# Interacting with named submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule named 'members' set up thus

```
[submodule "members"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = user@bitbucket.org:account/repo.git
```

I can interact with the submodule repo, so I know it's set up correctly.

When I run `git submodule update --remote 'members'` or `git submodule update --remote members` from the root of my project, I get the error `pathspec 'members' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Can anyone assist me with how to correctly interact with my submodule? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Either leave out the name of the submodule (then the command applies to all submodules) and just execute

```
git submodule update --remote
```

or, as the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) tells us,

> ```
> git submodule [--quiet] update [<options>] [--] [<path>…​]
> ```

specify the *path* to the submodule, not the *name*:

```
git submodule update --remote -- path/to/submodule
```

Comment: Thank you. I had hoped that setting it up with a name would mean I didn't have to use the whole path (it's long!) to update it. I guess not. Thanks again for the reply

Comment: That would make sense, I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to work that way. Maybe someone else knows more.

Comment: Turns out the final answer is at the link you gave me -- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/2.6.7#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---name. Seems like a waste of a beautiful opportunity!